# Button disabled if column is empty?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my EDIT.cshtml view page I would like the approve button to be set to disabled if the customer email record is empty. ATM I have it at appear or disappear depending on wether the email exists. I want to change this to disabled or enabled....Any ideas guys?

```
 @{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.Customer.Email))
    {
       <td><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Approvals")">Cancel</a></td>
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What is happening? What is returning? Please, give us more details.

Comment: jquery ? it does everything!

Comment: theres nothing wrong with my code...if the email exists the button appears...if it doesnt the button is not seen on screen....I want to change the button to disabled if the email does not exist(not hide it, which it currently does)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this once

```
@{
    <td><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Approvals")" @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Customer.Email) ? "disabled" : string.Empty)>Cancel</a></td>
}
```

CSS, Add style to make it diasble

```
button[disabled=disabled], button:disabled {
    // your css rules
}
```

Comment: good job that worked, thanks for reply....now I was thinking of changing it to an actual button...how would I switch the code over to a button....<button type="submit" name="btnApprove" @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Customer.Email) ? "disabled" : string.Empty)>Approve</button> and change to suit? would this work?

Comment: ok cool thanks that worked.....it is disabled...but it doesnt look disabled...how can i change its appearance, so visually the user will know what state its in??? thanks for the help

Comment: @John, for disabled button you have to play with css